# CakePHP: Can I Promote active router with Router::promote or some other way?

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

I've got two or more routes that will be going to the same controller and action. This is fine until I want to use a helper such as the form helper or pagination on the page.
What happens is that the current url changes to whatever is declared first in my `routes.php` file.

I see there is a way to [promote a router with Router::promote](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router%3a%3apromote) but I'm not sure if I can do it based on the current url or router being used or if there's a bett way to do this.

Here's an example of what my `router.php` looks like:

```
Router::connect('/cars-for-sale/results/*', array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'results'));
Router::connect('/new-cars/results/*', array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'results'));
Router::connect('/used-cars/results/*', array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'results'));
```

Let's say for example that I'm at the url `domain.com/used-cars/results/` and I'm using the form helper or pagination helper, the url that is being put in the action or href is `domain.com/cars-for-sale/results/`.

Any help or info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Routes should be unique and identifiable!

The problem with these Routes is that, basically, you created **duplicate URLs** not only does this cause problems with CakePHP picking the right route, Google doesn't like that as well; duplicated content will have a negative effect on your SEO ranking!

In order to pick the right URL (Route), CakePHP should be able to do so, based on its parameters; your current Routes do not offer any way to distinguish them.

And neither does your application!

All these URLs will present the same data;

```
/cars-for-sale/results/
/new-cars/results/
/used-cars/results/
```

### Solution 1 - separate actions

If your application is limited to these three categories, the easiest solution is to create three actions, one per category;

Controller:

```
class ListingsController extends AppController
{
    const CATEGORY_NEW       = 1;
    const CATEGORY_USED      = 2;
    const CATEGORY_FOR_SALE  = 3;

    public $uses = array('Car');


    public function forSaleCars()
    {
        $this->set('cars', $this->Paginator->paginate('Car', array('Car.category_id' => self::CATEGORY_FOR_SALE)));
    }

    public function newCars()
    {
        $this->set('cars', $this->Paginator->paginate('Car', array('Car.category_id' => self::CATEGORY_NEW)));
    }

    public function usedCars()
    {
        $this->set('cars', $this->Paginator->paginate('Car', array('Car.category_id' => self::CATEGORY_USED)));
    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
Router::connect(
    '/cars-for-sale/results/*', 
    array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'forSaleCars')
);
Router::connect(
    '/new-cars/results/*', 
    array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'newCars')
);
Router::connect(
    '/used-cars/results/*', 
    array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'usedCars')
);
```

### Solution 2 - Pass the 'category' as parameter

If the list of URLs to be used for the 'listings' will not be fixed and will expand, it may be better to pass the 'filter' as a parameter and include that in your routes;

routes.php

```
Router::connect(
    '/:category/results/*',
    array(
         'controller' => 'listings',
         'action'     => 'results',
    ),
    array(

         // category: lowercase alphanumeric and dashes, but NO leading/trailing dash
         'category'  => '[a-z0-9]{1}([a-z0-9\-]{2,}[a-z0-9]{1})?',

         // Mark category as 'persistent' so that the Html/PaginatorHelper
         // will automatically use the current category to generate links
         'persist'   => array('category'),

         // pass the category as parameter for the 'results' action
         'pass'      => array('category'),
    )
);
```

Read about the [Router API](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#router-api)

In your controller:

```
class ListingsController extends AppController
{
    public $uses = array('Car');


    /**
     * Shows results for the specified category
     *
     * @param string $category
     *
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function results($category = null)
    {
        $categoryId = $this->Car->Category->field('id', array('name' => $category));

        if (!$categoryId) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Unknown category'));
        }

        $this->set('cars', $this->Paginator->paginate('Car', array('Car.category_id' => $categoryId)));
    }
}
```

And, to create a link to a certain category;

```
$this->Html->link('New Cars', 
    array(
         'controller' => 'listings', 
         'action'     => 'results', 
         'category'   => 'new-cars'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer thaJeztah. I actually decided to break it unto separate actions before coming across your response. I was just trying to over simplify things I guess and eliminate redundancy. But some times it make more sense to repeat stuff in order to gain more functionality.